# issue running "afl-fuzz -Q" with binary libraries

Tags: android, fuzzer, android-native-library

I am trying to use `afl-fuzz` to find security vulnerabilities in Android native libraries (ex. `libssl.so`, `libhttp.so`, etc).

It's my understanding that I am supposed to use QEMU since `afl` by itself is not sufficient to find bugs without the source code.

When attempting to run the following:

```
#> afl-fuzz -Q -i input -o output -- ./libssl.so
```

I run into the following issue:

```
[-] The current memory limit (200 MB) is too restrictive, causing an OOM fault
    in the dynamic linker.
```

Which I managed to solve by setting the memory restrictions to "none". Then, I ran into this error:

```
[-] Hmm, looks like the target binary terminated before we could complete
    a handshake with the injected code. Perhaps there is a horrible bug in
    the fuzzer.
```

I just started to use `afl` recently so I am not quite familiar with how to use it especially with binary libraries. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all it am not sure you really need to run AFL in the `-Q` mode for fuzzing open-source libraries. You should better recompile it with `afl-gcc` to get the instrumentation installed in the binary. Then, it will be much easier (and quicker) to fuzz the whole application.

In fact, you run in `-Q` mode only when you have a binary only program to fuzz (I mean, you do not have sources of it).

Then, `afl` is basically working by creating partially random inputs for the fuzzed program. I do not exactly understand what you expect to do with a library as it has **absolutely no inputs** (it plugs to another program but that's all).

So, you may consider reading a bit more about fuzzing and sotfware I/O, it would probably the best way to go before trying to do more complex things.